# How to apply Bootstrap 4 select styling on dropdown links eg: a tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

What I want:
To apply bootstrap 4 form styling such as `form-control`, `custom-select`, to actual links(dropdown a tag)

like this:

```
<select class="custom-select" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option selected>Choose a website</option>
        <option value="google.com">google</option>
        <option value="apple.com">apple</option>
        <option value="amazon.com">amazon</option>
</select>
```

the styling is perfect and it works as intended but it's not actual links, What I really want is for it to be actual links but with the select styling, A tag, like this:

```
<select class="custom-select"> # or class = form-control
        <a href>Choose a website</a> # same styling as options but acutal links
        <a href="google.com">google</a>
        <a href="apple.com">apple</a>
        <a href="amazon.com">amazon</a>
</select>
```

I did find a way but it lags the page and not as clean, here's how I did it:

```
<div>
     <a href="#ChooseWeb" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle form-control">Choose a website</a>
           <style>
                 .form-control{
                  height: auto;
                 }
           </style>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled form-control" id="ChooseWeb">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">google</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">neflix</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">apple</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">amazon</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</div>
```

What is the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: Is this helpful: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/#single-button ?

Comment: I have tried that, didn't work, It's an a tag dropdown with button styling, What I want is a tag dropdown with form selection styling, such as "custom-select" or "form control"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand very well your question ( with all the a tags :) ) but I'm trying my best. In the link that I sent you if you scroll down a bit you'll find another way to do a dropdown with `a` tags (you can find for "And with <a> elements:" in the page), then you can change the `a` style to your liking

Comment: I don't think it works, care to share a snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eyxs3a9j/12/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mqy08tvf/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236918/discussion-between-n00b-and-hello-world).

Comment: I have made some adjustments, It does the job, But not as clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a dropdown using only `a` tags, use bootstrap "[Dropdown single button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/#single-button)" component with "`<a>` elements".
Now to make it look like bootstrap `.custom-select` class, simply copy bootstraps css style of that class (`.custom-select`) and adapt it to the dropdown you just created, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/5nwjmt9h/1/

Here's bootstraps css style for `.custom-select`:

```css
.custom-select {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
   padding: .375rem 1.75rem .375rem .75rem;
   font-size: 1rem;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 1.5;
   color: #495057;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background: #fff url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='4' height='5' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3e%3cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") right .75rem center/8px 10px no-repeat;
   border: 1px solid #ced4da;
   border-radius: .25rem;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```